# Before Insert Trigger SOQL Limits

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, governorlimits, before-trigger

I am building a before insert trigger on hed__Program_Enrollment__c. What I am trying to do is delete everything in the hed__Program_Enrollment__c table based on a certain condition and this seems to be hitting the 100 SOQL limit error as I receive the following: System.LimitException: hed:Too many SOQL queries: 101

The code giving me trouble is below. The one SOQL statement I have, I expect to return a few 100 rows from the condition specified and then I just want to delete them. How can I do this so I don't hit the limit.

```
trigger ProgTrigger on hed__Program_Enrollment__c (before insert) {

list<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> myProg = new list<hed__Program_Enrollment__c>();


myProg = [SELECT ID, NAME FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c where Value__c = '200'];

for(hed__Program_Enrollment__c prog: myProg) {
    delete prog;
}

}
```

Comment: what exactly line throws this exception?

Comment: I am not sure about the line, but every time a delete occurs the SOQL count goes up by 1.

Comment: you should not create a delete into a loop. Put it in a list and after, delete

Comment: Does the error message not mention the line #?

Comment: Please provide which line throws an exception. Your provided code could throw an exception of too many dml operations, but not SOQL query limit. I assume, managed package throws this exception.

Comment: I see this in my log  DML_END|[29]
|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[29]|Bytes:34
|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: hed:Too many SOQL queries: 101

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi your previous answer delete [SELECT ID, NAME FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c where Value__c = '200']; solved my issue. I am now not getting any SOQL limit error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, delete dml invokes some trigger in managed package, which throws an SOQL limit exception.

Overall, it is possible to use dml not for the single record, but for the collections of 
 the records. Move `delete prog;` outside of the loop

```
trigger ProgTrigger on hed__Program_Enrollment__c (before insert) {
    list<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> myProg = [SELECT ID, NAME FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c where Value__c = '200'];
    delete myProg;
}
```

you can even more just to call `delete` for query:

```
trigger ProgTrigger on hed__Program_Enrollment__c (before insert) {
    delete [SELECT ID, NAME FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c where Value__c = '200'];
}
```

---

I recommend reading [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices). It highlights your problem as *Best Practice #2: Avoid SOQL Queries or DML statements inside FOR Loops*

Answer (score 0):

You need to bulkify your code, try not to put logic in the trigger, move the logic to a handler/helper. Also avoid doing DML operations inside a loop, you're going to hit another limit soon.

```
// ProgTrigger
ProgTriggerHandler.handleEnrollmentDeletion(Trigger.NEW);

// ProgTriggerHandler#handleEnrollmentDeletion
Map<Id, hed__Program_Enrollment__c > enrollments = new Map<Id, hed__Program_Enrollment__c>(newItems);
List<hed__Program_Enrollment__c> enrollemntsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM hed__Program_Enrollment__c WHERE Id IN :enrollments.keySet() AND Value__c = '200'];

delete enrollmentsToDelete;
```

Well, I just realized I coded as in an after insert... but that's not the point. Best practices to avoid hitting limits is.